# Extract data from Geopackage .gpkg using lat long bounds

Tags: geopackage

I have a **.gpkg.tar.gz** data file whose size is 3.8 GiB. Uncompressed to .gpkg, its size is 8.5 GiB.

It is spanning a large geographical area. I want to extract data from this for a small area, given by lat-long bounds.

It is fine if there are features in/crossing this area but extending beyond it - I don't want to bother with chopping/clipping features. But I want to exclude features that are entirely outside of the given bounds.

With .pbf (Openstreetmap) data I have a way of doing this, example:

```
osmconvert india-latest.osm.pbf -b=78.55834,12.54397,80.3558,13.71654 --complete-ways -o=small.pbf
```

Is there a similar command / process we can do with .gpkg?

I understand it is originally SQLite; and I've read that one doesn't need to load the entire file into memory to work with that. So some specific queries - table names, column names might be there? This file is too big for me to load up in QGIS etc at the moment to be able to investigate its contents.

Ref: http://www.geopackage.org/index.html

Comment: Use ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with `-spat` parameter. The whole command would be like `ogr2ogr -f gpkg -spat 12.54397 78.55834 13.71654 80.3558 output.gpkg input.gpkg`.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the other question. It hadn't come up when I searched because I had different words. I think the other question has more complexity; it would be good to leave this question up so it can catch people looking for the same thing and then take them to the right place.